# sentiment analysis-training for 3 classes sentiment using 2 classes dataset

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-transformers, stocktwits, sentimentr

I'm going to build a model for twitter sentiment on Financial market using transformers. I have access to StockTwits data for training, which only contains positive and negative sentiments. However, I would like to consider 3 classes, positive, negative and neutral. My question is it a safe way to use 2 class data for training a model with 3 classes?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your model will not learn what neutral is. Maybe you want to look for zero-shot classification or label some samples by yourself.